# How to stream song in chunks to audio player in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, wavesurfer.js

I want to play a song from a remote server using a url, but when i try to do that it takes a long time for the song to download and start playing.

I want to be able to fetch the song from the url in chunks and pass into my audio player, in this case -wavesurfer.js

```
let wavesurfer.song = URL

wavesurfer.load(waveform.song, waveform.backend.peaks)
wavesurfer.playPause()
```

How can i make it that the song comes in, in chunks and get passed into the audio player, so that it can play immediately